# Disable All Chrome Notifications on PC

Tags: google-chrome, notifications

I'd like to temporarily disable all notifications from Chrome quickly. All notifications include:

- Website notifications (Facebook)
- Notifications from apps/extensions

How would I do this? Goal is to be able to toggle this on/off, maybe even allowing snoozing.

Comment: For Windows OS: right click speaker in tray, select "Open Volume Mixer", find Chrome and mute/unmute it. Of course if there is nothing playing you will not see it, so just open a you tube video to get chrome visible in the mixer and it will stick as long as you have the volume mixer window open. Not the nicest way but it works :) no snoozing though

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new Chrome extension that does exactly what you described: [Chrome Do Not Distrub](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-do-not-disturb/kidgbjjjkhkickaakajjpgdkcfnidphn). Try it out!